# xamarin-studio and hyper-v machines

Tags: xamarin-studio

I would like to setup Xamarin-studio on a hyper-v machine is that possible or not ? Because I've tried that twice and didn't work, I always got this error after installation and running Xamarin-studio :

[image: emulator]

Comment: share the error

Comment: Instead of sharing link to the image, include the error as text in your question